# New install of Xubuntu 14.04 crashes overnight after a few days uptime, how to diagnose?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu

I recently installed xubuntu 14.04.1 on a computer that previously ran ubuntu 10.04. The machine was completely stable while running 10.04 and would run for weeks or months without reboot, so I think I can rule out hardware problems, right?

Since installing 14.04.1, it has crashed twice over the last two weekends. When I come into the office on a Monday morning, the machine is completely unresponsive, not even to REISUB. Only a hard reset is possible.

I cannot find anything in the logs. In syslog, there are fairly harmless looking warnings, cron reports, etc. every hour or so, showing that the machine was still alive. Then they just stop. For the latest crash, the last message in syslog is this:

```
Sep  7 04:43:53 zooey avahi-daemon[857]: Invalid response packet from host <IP_ADDRESS>.
Sep  7 04:43:53 zooey avahi-daemon[857]: Invalid response packet from host <MAC_ADDRESS>.
```

But similar errors had been occurring every 50 minutes in the log prior to the crash, so I doubt that has anything to do with it.

Are there any other log files I should be looking at? Any ideas? Thanks in advance.